cannot open source file nlohmann/adl_serializer.h in json.hpp
I am getting error:
cannot open source file nlohmann/adl_serializer.h in json.hpp
I have included json.hpp after correctly installing nlohmann-json via vcpkg but getting above error.
When I am checking the path of adl_serializer.h, it is present at correct location but still getting the error.
#include "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\cpp\vcpkg\buildtrees\nlohmann-json\src\v3.11.3-434e7fbc3e.clean\single_include\nlohmann\json.hpp";
It is working on one system, and not working on other.
I tried to unistalling and then installing it again but its the same.
Tried to clean build and run the project again.
